# C++ How to return a private variable of derived class from base class object

Tags: c++, inheritance

I am trying to use functions that sets-gets a private variable of a derived class from base class objects. I think that is working for the void setC function but when i am trying to compile the getC function i get an error "Control reaches and non-void function". Is the whole concept possible?

```
class BASE{
    int a, b;
public:
    BASE(){}

    BASE(int a, int b){
        this->a = a;
        this->b = b;
    }
    void setC(int){}
    int getC(){}
};

class Derived : public BASE{
    int c;
public:
    void setC(int c) {
        this->c = c;
    }
    int getC() {
        return c;
    }
};


int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

vector<BASE> d;

d.push_back(BASE(1,1));

d[0].setC(5);
cout << d[0].getC();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Implement `getC` and `setC` as (pure) virtual functions. And instantiate using derived class, like this:

```
class BASE {
public:
    virtual void setC(int c) = 0;
    virtual int getC() = 0;
};
class Derived : public BASE {
    int c;
public:
    virtual void setC(int c) { this->c = c; }
    virtual int getC() { return c; }
};

void main() {
    vector<BASE*> d;
    d.push_back(new Derived());
    d[0]->setC(5);
    cout << d[0]->getC();
    delete d[0];
}
```

PS. You got that error message because your `BASE::getC` doesn't return a value.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get polymorphic behavior for getC(), you need the vector to be a vector of pointers, and declare getC and setC as virtual functions.

```
vector<BASE*> d;
```

Then

```
d.push_back(new DERIVED(1,1));
```

Will insert a new DERIVED object, and then

```
d[0]->getC()
```

will return the value from the derived object.

Comment: Note there are other, more complex, ways to get similar behaviour that do not rely on the vector (directly) storing pointers.

Comment: Interesting. Can you elaborate?

Comment: pImpl used to fake a value semantics type, like how `std::function` is (usually) implemented?